# How do I receive an email with Amazon SES after verifying a Route53 domain

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

How do I receive an email with Amazon SES after for an account on a  Route53 domain that has been verified and MX records set ?

- I already own the domain and it is hosted on Route53
- I didnt have anything setup for email for that domain, it was just used to redirect http requests to another domain (one .com, the other .net)
- I have now SES verified the domain including accepting the MX records.
- I then sent a test email to an email (from an email for a verified address that I do have email configured and it is not on a domain under Amazon control)
- I have not received this email because I have not configured my email client to receive emails from the account.

**But how do I find what the settings are to get email from this verified Route 53 controlled domain, or is this not possible.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible.

SES inbound email is designed around automated processing of inbound messages -- not mailboxes and email clients.  That's why mail targets include S3 buckets, Lambda functions, and SNS topics.

For actual mailboxes, you need a service like [Amazon Workmail](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/), which supports IMAP, and can be integrated with SES.

Comment: So if i verify a domain and set the MX record that AWS provides does that stop me receiving email for that domain in the usual way

Comment: Yes.  Any given domain can only have its mail delivered to one authoritative system. Such a system may have multiple mail exchangers, but they all need to result in identical final delivery behavior, so you can't combine MX from independent systems.  Depending on how you use the email, you may want to associate a subdomain with SES inbound, instead of the main domain -- e.g. configure SES to receive incoming mail sent to `notifications.example.com` instead of `example.com`.

Comment: What is the easiest way within the AWS infrastructure to receive those emails that have been sent to this domain.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, here, when you say "receive those emails that have been sent to this domain."

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to retrieve messages sent to this domain between now and back when you set it up?  It depends on how you configured it, whether there are any messages or how you might access them.

Comment: Yes, or if its impossible for me to retrieve those messages what is the simplest setup so that I can retrieve future email messages using AWS